# How can I connect an EasyADC board mikroe340?

Tags: gpio, analog-to-digital

I've got a 4-channel 12-bit ADC "Mikroe340" from Mikroelektronika ([datasheet](http://www.datasheetlib.com/datasheet/1014431/mikroe-340_mikroelektronika.html)). I'm wondering how to wire it with GPIO.

[image: !(http://static4.tme.eu/products_pics/3/d/7/3d785623be45a644c66a1632ed688914/73330.jpg)]

Comment: The photo is pretty.  A link to the specs will be more useful.

Comment: here is the datasheet: (http://www.datasheetlib.com/datasheet/1014431/mikroe-340_mikroelektronika.html)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

What an odd board.  I'd have just gone for a MCP3204 and stuck it in a breadboard - but I'm strictly a hobbyist.

I'd set the DIP switches for a PIC so 1 on, 4 on, 6 on, others off.

That will connect MISO to P4, MOSI to P5, and SCLK to P3.

So the Pi connections to make would be

```
          Pi         340   Function
(gpio 10) Pin 19     P5    MOSI
(gpio 9)  Pin 21     P4    MISO
(gpio 11) Pin 23     P3    SCLK
(gpio 8)  Pin 24     CS    chip select
          Pin 1      VCC   VCC (3V3 as Pi gpios can't handle 5V)
          Pin 6      GND   Ground
```